# My code has multiple errors when used at a large scale that i didnt see in smale scale tests

Tags: python, recursion

I'm relatively Ok at using python for intermediate tasks but have very little understanding of the more technical parts of syntax. I wanted the below code to generate every possible combination of dice, I chose to do this by using a recursive function. When tested with three dice this worked fine without any errors being raised. I moved onto five dice but found that this would trigger a recursion depth error:

print(dicelist)
RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while pickling an object

I did my research and found that the following code can be used to prevent this:
`sys.setrecursionlimit(4000)`

However when used in conjunction with my code it gets about 80% complete then stops printing to IDLE waits a few secs and then displays the shell restart message. I also looked at this and came to a loose end, I tried the tests suggested by some people to check IDLE was working correctly and apparently IDLE's fine its just the code.

Furthermore, when the print statement is removed( it was only intended for testing, it would later be replaced with a system that would move the dice combinations to a .txt file) the code refused to run and threw this up:

if pos == level and dicelist[pos] == 7:
RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded in comparison

If the print statement was removed and the recursion limit was increased with the code I showed earlier it once again crashed and displayed the shell restart message.

To conclude, my questions are:

Is the shell restart linked to me including the code that increases the recursion limit?
Why does the debug call the recursion error at the print statement as I thought this wouldn't increase the stack?
Can this be sorted with subtle code rewrites or is my system totally flawed and will need to be fully re-written?

```
import sys
##sys.setrecursionlimit(4000)
dicelist = [1, 1, 1, 1, 1] ## wthe number of dice can be changed by adding or removing entries form this list
length = len(dicelist) - 1
pos = len(dicelist) - 1
level = len(dicelist) - 1

def iterate():
    global pos, level, dicelist, length
    ##print(dicelist)
    terminate = True
    for i in range(0, len(dicelist)):
        if dicelist[i] != 6:
            terminate = False
    iteratecheck()
    if pos > length:
        pos = length
    if terminate == False:
        iterate() 


def iteratecheck():
    global pos, level, dicelist, length
    dicelist[pos] += 1
    if pos == level and dicelist[pos] == 7:
        level -= 1
        dicelist[pos] = 1
        pos = level
        iteratecheck()
    elif dicelist[pos] == 7:
        dicelist[pos] = 1
        pos -= 1
        iteratecheck()
    else:
        pos += 1
    if pos > length:
        pos = length

iterate()
```

BTW this is my first post so I might have missed something

Comment: A call to `print` is a function call, so it will use space on the stack. And ideally, if there's any chance that a recursive function will cause a stack overflow/"recursion error", recursion shouldn't be used. Any mitigation like `setrecursionlimit` will be a temporary fix unless you can guarantee that a function will never exceed a certain number of recurses. If you can't guarantee that, recursion will always be a problem. I'd try to rewrite this with an iterative implementation.

Comment: Make sure though that the function isn't just broken. If it's recursing more than you expect it to, that can be a sign of a bug.

Comment: Is there any way to optimise the code to prevent any issues being raised without having to do a major rewrite. Also can you explain why the shell crashed?

Comment: I could remove the parts where iteratecheck() calls itself and instead use a few if statements, would that help?

Comment: EDIT: I didn't realise that there are cases in which I iteratecheck() has to call itself multiple time in a row thus it cannot be removed.

Comment: Yes. From running your code, it seems like the problem is simply "too big" to be feasible with recursion once you go past 3-4 dice. I know this defeats the purpose of this project, but if you need combinations/permutations, you should really use [existing solutions](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations) that don't have these shortfalls.

Comment: Would you be able to explain what I put in the ` itertools.combinations() ` function, I cant figure out how to simulate x amount of dice, for example with 5 dice you should get 6^5 answers but sometimes I got more or less but never exactly that many, is that the wrong function or do I need to put something specific into it?

Comment: As an aside, there's a built-in function to do just this: [`itertools.combinations()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations).

Answer (score 0):

the code

```
    terminate = True
    for i in range(0, len(dicelist)):
        if dicelist[i] != 6:
            terminate = False
```

has me troubled.  Essentially the value of terminate is only set for the variable `dicelist[len(dicelist0-1)]`  You seem to be looping through all the dice to evaluate them, but just overwrite your variable.  I'm guessing you might have intended

```
    terminate = True
    for i in range(0, len(dicelist)):
        if dicelist[i] != 6:
            terminate = False and terminate
```

because that would have any `False` persist... I'm not really certain where your intent is.  Also, since you are evaluating a boolean to generate a boolean, there is a possibility to condense it.

```
    terminate = True
    for i in range(0, len(dicelist)):
        terminate = terminate and dicelist[i] == 6
```

I will admit I haven't dug too deep into your code, but I love recursion and this jumped out at me.

Comment: Thank you, didn't realise I had an answer until just now!. I believe the code I wrote was correctly performing its intended function, when all of the dice were equal to 6 my program would end. The reason I set it up the way I did was such that if a non six was ever detected the code wouldn't accidentally end the run. The bit of condensed code does however work so I am thankful for that. As suggested by a previous comment I started using itertools() however I am still very interested by this and recursion in general.